# Android google map v2 maven

Tags: android, maven, google-maps-android-api-2

I am creating an android application using google maps and maven.  I put in my pom.xml two dependencies

```
       <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
        <version>4</version>
        <type>apklib</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
        <version>4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

The apklib and jar appears in the maven repository.(m2\repository)

main_map.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/mainLay"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <fragment 
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I put the permissions and the metadatada with the api key in my AndroidManifest.

```
 <permission
    android:name="com.map.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.map.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permissionndroid:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyDRDsq0vAYySrs__0a8Yb2yr333W_z1uAo" />
```

MainActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap map;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_map.xml);

    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
 }
}
```

I got this exception

```
04-18 10:32:37.939: E/AndroidRuntime(21550): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 10:32:37.939: E/AndroidRuntime(21550): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
04-18 10:32:37.939: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
04-18 10:32:37.939: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
04-18 10:32:37.939: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:269)
04-18 10:32:37.939: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
04-18 10:32:37.939: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
04-18 10:32:37.939: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
04-18 10:32:37.939: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-18 10:32:37.939: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-18 10:32:37.939: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
04-18 10:32:37.939: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
04-18 10:32:37.939: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):    at com.codespring.androidspeed.ui.newui.MainPager.onCreate(MainPager.java:62)
04-18 10:32:37.939: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-18 10:32:37.939: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
04-18 10:32:37.939: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
04-18 10:32:37.939: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-18 10:32:37.939: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-18 10:32:37.939: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-18 10:32:37.939: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-18 10:32:37.939: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3729)
04-18 10:32:37.939: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 10:32:37.939: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-18 10:32:37.939: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
04-18 10:32:37.939: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:632)
04-18 10:32:37.939: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Anyone can help me about this?

Comment: Did you referenced the Google play services library?

Comment: Yes. I try to use google-play-services in a maven project. I put the dependencies in the pom.xml but i got this error.

Comment: Just my 2 cents: why are you not using the version 5 of the library?

Comment: With the version 5 the maven compiler gives this error Failure to find com.google.android.gms:google-play-services:jar:5.

Comment: Update the library with the Android SDK Manager and redeploy it to your local repository with Maven SDK Deployer: http://bit.ly/ZBD7zf

Answer (score 0):

I have a maven build set up in my project.

Here are relevant pom files:

http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/source/browse/android-maps-extensions/pom.xml

http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/source/browse/android-maps-extensions-demo/pom.xml

This is not clear Google Maps Android API v2, but a lib based on it.

How are you starting the app? You should be doing `mvn android:deploy android:run`. I find running maven from Eclipse buggy (but maybe I'm doing something wrong).